# Edit with viewmodel in entity frameworkcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper

Hello I have a problem is that I cannot edit my model using a viewmodel and I tried to integrate the automapping but it did not work because in my viewmodel I have models at the Palce of properties I would like to know is if there is another simpler solution to make it work

error : System.InvalidOperationException : 'The instance of entity type 'SeDevisTest' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'DevisId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

thank you

```
this is my Controller

   public ActionResult edit(ViewModelEtudes viewModelEtudes)
    {
        ViewModelEtudes Etudes = new ViewModelEtudes();
        serviceEtudesEnCours.remplirDrowdownliste(demId);

        var resultDevis= _context.SeDevisTest.FirstOrDefault(item => item.DevisFkDemNum == demId);

        if (resultDevis != null)
        {
           
            _context.Entry(viewModelEtudes.SeDevisTest).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();

          

        }

       

        return View(Etudes);
    }
```

this is my view model it contains the entity that I will change se_devis

```
public class ViewModelEtudes
{
    public SeDevisTest SeDevisTest { get; set; }
    public SeDemande seDemandes { get; set; }
    public SeInformationRecrutement InformationRecrutement { get; set; }

    public SeControleProduit controleProduit { get; set; }

    public SeQuestionnaire questionnaire { get; set; }
    public SePersonnelSyres SePersonnelSyres { get; set; }
    public SeTypeProduit SeTypeProduit { get; set; }
    public List<SeCritereTest> SeCritereTest { get; set; }
    public SePartenir sePartenirs { get; set; }
    public SeTraitementDemande seTraitementDemandes { get; set; }
    public SeInformationClient SeInformationClient { get; set; }
    public SeClient SeInclient { get; set; }
    public SeAssistantClient assitantclient { get; set; }
    public SeReceptionProduit receptionProduit { get; set; }
    public SePrestation prestation { get; set; }
    public SeRapport seRapport { get; set; }
    public SeResultat seResultat { get; set; }
    public SeDemandeTypeProduit demandeTypeProduit { get; set; }
    
   }
```

this is my Entity SE_DEVIS_TEST

```
       public SeDevisTest()
    {
        Correspondance = new HashSet<Correspondance>();
        SeCorrecponsance = new HashSet<SeCorrecponsance>();
        SeFacture = new HashSet<SeFacture>();
        SePlainte = new HashSet<SePlainte>();
        SeQuestionnaire = new HashSet<SeQuestionnaire>();
        SeRapport = new HashSet<SeRapport>();
    }

    public int DevisId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DevisDateCreation { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DevisDateEnvoi { get; set; }
    public bool? DevisAnnulation { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DevisDateAnnulation { get; set; }
    public int? DevisMotifAnnulationDesc { get; set; }
    public bool? DevisConserverFacturation { get; set; }
    public bool? DevisSigneReçu { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DevisDateReception { get; set; }
    public bool? DevisAttestationReçu { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DevisDateReceptionAttestation { get; set; }
    public string DevisConditionParticuliere { get; set; }
    public int? DevisFkDemNum { get; set; }
    public int? DevisFkSatisfaClientId { get; set; }
    public int? DevisDiffcultéEstimé { get; set; }
    public string DevisSy { get; set; }
    public int? DevisNbRapport { get; set; }

    public virtual SeQualiDifficulte DevisDiffcultéEstiméNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual SeTraitementDemande DevisFkDemNumNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual SeSatisfactionClient DevisFkSatisfaClient { get; set; }
    public virtual SeColisage SeColisage { get; set; }
    public virtual SeGestionBase SeGestionBase { get; set; }
    public virtual SeInformationRecrutement SeInformationRecrutement { get; set; }
    public virtual SeLettre SeLettre { get; set; }
    public virtual SeOrganistationRecrutement SeOrganistationRecrutement { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Correspondance> Correspondance { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SeCorrecponsance> SeCorrecponsance { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SeFacture> SeFacture { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SePlainte> SePlainte { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SeQuestionnaire> SeQuestionnaire { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SeRapport> SeRapport { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You get `resultDevis` from the database and then also try to attach `viewModelEtudes.SeDevisTest`.

Comment: how i can attach it

Comment: No, I mean, you attach two different objects with the same `DevisId`, one by getting it from the database, the second one is attached by setting its state.